# Proof the sequence $z_n=px_n+qy_n$ converges implies sequence $x_n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to prove that the sequence $x_n$ converges, given that the above sequence $z_n=px_n+qy_n$ converges, and that:

- $p,q\ >0$ and $p+q = 1$
- $\displaystyle{ \forall n,\ y_n = \sum_{k=1}^n t_{n,k} x_k }$
- $\forall k,\ t_{n,k} > 0$, $t_{n,k} \xrightarrow[n]{} 0$, and $\displaystyle{ \sum_{k=1}^n t_{n,k} = 1}$

Comment: Man.. this is surprisingly hard! The only thing I can prove so far is that $\{ x_n \}$ is bounded if it doesn't change sign for $n$ greater than some $N$. It makes me think of Abel's test and Abel/Tauber theorems, but I can't put the finger on it :S Love this question!